# How to find/figure out the minimum supply current for a device?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

I am using a MOSFET controller [ZXGD3113W6](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXGD3113W6.pdf) to essentially work with a MOSFET as an ideal diode and I need to check the minimum supply current (to VCC) to ensure full operation and wasn't sure how to work this out and can't seem to find any details on the datasheet. Any ideas?

If it's relevant the MOSFET it will be driving is the [PSMN075-100MSE](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN075-100MSE.pdf).

Comment: Datasheet only lists 6.2 mA nominal, no maximum. Ask the manufacturer? Assume 2x nominal?

Comment: Give us a schematic of your intended "ideal diode" setup!

Answer (score 1):

Your mosfet driver lists quiescent current to be 6.2 mA. That is how much current it needs while doing nothing.
That will then sum with the gate drive current, which depends on what kind of transistor you are using and how you are driving it (gate voltage, driving signal frequency, gate resistance, gate capacitance). Your datasheeet contains plots for all of this
[image]